# nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

```
    @Override
    public int saved(Register r) {
        String sql = "insert into tbl_register(fname,lname,email,phone,address,username,password,gender,use)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        return JdbcTemplate.update(sql,r.getFname(), r.getLname(), r.getEmail(), r.getPhone(), r.getAddress(), r.getUsername(), r.getPassword(), r.getGender(), r.getUse());
    }
```

Comment: can you provide the table definition, please?

Comment: Check for spaces around values. Those are missing.